# Does GCC's __attribute__((__packed__)) retain the original ordering?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, networking, struct

**Purpose**

I am writing a network program in C (specifically `gnu89`) and I would like to simplify things by reinterpreting a certain `struct X` as big array of bytes (a.k.a. `char`), sending the bytes over the network, and reinterpreting them as `struct X` on the other side. To this end I have decided to use gcc's __attribute__((__packed__ )). I have done my best to ensure that this is done correctly (i.e. I've accounted for endianness and other related issues).

**Question**

Other than guaranteeing that `struct X` is as small as possible, does gcc guarantee that a `struct` defined with __attribute__((__packed__ )) retains the original ordering? I've done a fair amount of searching and I have yet to find any documentation on whether or not this guarantee exists.

**Notes**

It is safe to assume that both the sender and receiver will encounter no portability issues (e.g. `sizeof(int)` on the server is equal to `sizeof(int)` on the client).

Comment: What do you mean by "original ordering"?  Do you mean are the struct members literally in the same order as specified in the definition?

Comment: Given that you are writing a network program, you are probably headed for a world of pain when your data goes to a machine using a SPARC or PowerPC chip, to name but two families, when the source is an Intel chip.  Also, if you do anything other than load and send the data with the packed structures, the performance hit from accessing the packed data is probably a lot worse than you writing the code to serialize the data in a platform neutral way from unpacked data structures.  Also, well designed data structures don't have random holes in them - it is possible to do it.

Comment: +1 to Jonathan's comment above. Redesign your struct so it doesn't have holes in it in the first line. (Largest to smallest element should usually suffice.)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I am writing this program for personal use only. I know the architectures of the connecting machines beforehand.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming that you are asking whether the struct members will retain the order specified in their definition, the answer is yes.  The Standard requires that successive members have increasing addresses:

Section §6.7.2.1p13:

> Within a
>   structure object, the non-bit-field
>   members and the units in which
>   bit-fields reside have addresses that
>   increase in the order in which they
>   are declared.

and the documentation for the packed attribute clearly states that only padding/alignment is affected:

> The packed attribute specifies that a
>   variable or structure field should
>   have the smallest possible
>   alignment—one byte for a variable, and
>   one bit for a field, unless you
>   specify a larger value with the
>   aligned attribute.

Comment: The GCC doc quote does not make it clear to me if bit field *ordering* is maintained.

Answer (score 40):

Yes, `__attribute__((packed))` (no need for second set of underscores) is a correct way to implement binary (i.e. non-text) network protocols. There will be no gaps between the elements.

However you should understand that `packed` not only packs the structure, but also:

- makes its required alignment one byte, and
- makes sure that its members, which may get misaligned by the packing and by lack of alignment requirement of the struct itself, are read and written correctly, i.e. **misalignment of its fields is dealt with in software by the compiler**.

**However**, the compiler will only deal with misalignment if you access the struct members directly. You should **never make a pointer to a member of a packed struct** (except when you know the member's required alignment is 1, like char or another packed struct). The following C code demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

struct packet {
    uint8_t x;
    uint32_t y;
} __attribute__((packed));

int main ()
{
    uint8_t bytes[5] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 2};
    struct packet *p = (struct packet *)bytes;

    // compiler handles misalignment because it knows that
    // "struct packet" is packed
    printf("y=%"PRIX32", ", ntohl(p->y));

    // compiler does not handle misalignment - py does not inherit
    // the packed attribute
    uint32_t *py = &p->y;
    printf("*py=%"PRIX32"\n", ntohl(*py));
    return 0;
}
```

On an x86 system (which does not enforce memory access alignment), this will produce

```
y=2, *py=2
```

as expected. On the other hand on my ARM Linux board, for example, it produced the seemingly wrong result

```
y=2, *py=1
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes.

However, using `__attribute__((__packed__))` is not a good way to do what you are doing.

- It doesn't resolve byte order issues
- Access to the structure will be slow
- Although the popularity of gcc has led to a situation where other compilers often implement gcc extensions, using this compiler-specific extension means that you do not have a conforming C program. This means that if another compiler or even a future gcc changes **packed** or doesn't implement it at all, you are out of luck and can't even complain to anyone. Gcc could drop it tomorrow and still be a C99 compiler.  (Ok, that exact thing is unlikely.) Most of us try to write conforming programs not because we have some abstract hostility to using vendor software or desire some academic standard of code purity, but rather because we know that only conforming language features have a precise and common specification, so it is far far easier to depend on our code doing the right thing from day to day and system to system if we do it that way.
- You are reinventing the wheel; this problem has already been solved in a standard-conforming way: see ***[YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)***, ***[XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML),*** and ***[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)***.
- If it's such a low-level protocol that YAML, XML, and JSON are not available, you really should take individual fundamental types, apply your host's version of hton?() and ntoh?(), and memcpy() them to an output buffer. I realize that there is a long tradition of reading and writing straight from structures, but I've also spent a long time fixing that code later when it was moved from 32-bit to 64-bit environments...

Comment: @DigitalRoss I am the first one to write code which strictly conforms to ISO C90. I never use compiler-specific hacks. However, in this case I am writing code entirely for personal use.

Comment: Well, I agree that my answer was not aimed at your question very well, I guess I'll delete it...

Comment: @DigitalRoss Don't delete the answer! It may help someone else who comes along to this thread.

Comment: If the OP only cares about "personal use" and has machines with the same byte ordering on both sides of the link, then it's almost certain that both sides also have the same alignment constraints. While alignment is implementation defined, that doesn't mean it's something that will change underneath you at every compiler revision. Preserving alignment behavior is essential to all but the most trivial use of library code, and gcc on x86 even excludes optimal alignment of `double` for the sake of maintaining compatibility with existing alignment ABI.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you're trying to do, I'd highly encourage you to also used fixed-size data types (ie. uint32_t, int16_t, etc) that are found in stdint.h.  Using fixed-size data types will prevent you from having to do things like the following:

```
struct name
{
    short field : 8;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

We use this technique frequently to convert messages between a byte array and a structure, and have never encountered problems with it.  You may have to perform endianness conversion yourself, but field order isn't a problem.  If you have any concerns about data type sizes, you can always specify field size like so:

```
struct foo
{
  short someField : 16 __attribute__ ((packed));
};
```

This guarantees that someField will be stored as 16 bits and will not be rearranged or altered to fit byte boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C has a guarantee that struct elements won't be reordered. (There may be extensions or fancy optimization systems that might change this, but not by default in gcc.)

Comment: C++ allows reordering of elements with intervening access specifiers. This doesn't affect the C subset of C++, as a C struct doesn't have any access specifiers at all.