# How can I get the sizes of various types in c?

Tags: c

I would like to know the size of following types in **C**,

`sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(float)`, `sizeof(double)`, `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(167)`, `sizeof(3.1415926)` and `sizeof(‘$’)`.

Comment: What are you talking about? A homework assignment?

Comment: I think he's looking for a 'system reference' program.  I.E., a program that will, for the specific compiler/cpu being used, output what the size of each of those types will be.

Comment: @user292489, is this a C or C# question?

Comment: @user292489, based on your comments and the retag, I've edited the question to hopefully make it more readable. It may or may not get reopened depending on the whims of the SO swarm :-)

Comment: Numerous other questions are similar, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067096/is-the-memory-alignment-different-for-different-data-types/2069328#2069328.  I have an updated version of the program there that can be used with C or C++ compilers (see my profile to contact me).

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You can use the following code. I'm answering in C since that's what the question asked for, despite the C# tag. If you really want C#, someone else will have to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    // Use %zu for size_t if your compiler supports it.
    printf("sizeof(int)       = %d\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(float)     = %d\n",sizeof(float));
    printf("sizeof(double)    = %d\n",sizeof(double));
    printf("sizeof(char)      = %d\n",sizeof(char));
    printf("sizeof(167)       = %d\n",sizeof(167));
    printf("sizeof(3.1415926) = %d\n",sizeof(3.1415926));
    printf("sizeof('$')       = %d\n",sizeof('$'));
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs (on my system):

```
sizeof(int)       = 4
sizeof(float)     = 4
sizeof(double)    = 8
sizeof(char)      = 1
sizeof(167)       = 4
sizeof(3.1415926) = 8
sizeof('$')       = 4
```

Keep in mind that this gives you the values in terms of bytes which, under the C standard, are *not* necessarily 8 bits. You should examine CHAR_BITS from `limits.h` to see how many bits are in a byte.

Comment: it was giving me an error when i compile it:
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
__gxx_personality_v0                /var/tmp//ccwLqbRS.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: 1) How are you compiling it? 2) What compiler are you using? 3) What OS are you using?

Comment: i was using gcc compiler and used the exact copy from the above program.

Comment: I'm noticing that the quotes around $ are 'smart quotes', and not plain ones. Is that a typo in the original program? Because that's not going to fly at all with any compiler (except MS Word perhaps)

Comment: You need to name the file with a .c extension.  Or compile with g++ instead of gcc.

Comment: Actually it worked fine under Ubuntu 9.10, Adriano, but I've changed it anyway :-) although the smart quotes were just inside the string, not part of the zizeof. @user292489, that personality problem is usually a C/C++ mismatch. Make sure your program is called something.c and use "gcc -o something something.c" to compile it.

Comment: I'm going to be pedantic here and point out that `sizeof` returns an `unsigned` type, while `%d` implies a signed integer.  On a 64-bit big-endian computer, this is very likely to print 0 for all cases.  Over fifteen years ago, a student of mine got that result on a Macintosh with a 32-bit `size_t` and 16-bit `int`.

Comment: @user292489: the error you are getting is a linker error and means that you have a variable or function that is not defined in any of the object files or libraries. You should edit your question and outline the exact steps you are taking.

Comment: @user292489: (1) What computer? (2) What OS? (3) What is your compile command? Please answer these questions before trying anything else.

Comment: @user292489@: to answer paxdiablo's question precisely, just copy what the command "gcc -v" or "gcc --version" gives you

Comment: here is the program that i tried to compile: #include <stdio.h> int main (void) { printf("sizeof(int): %d\n",sizeof(int)); printf("sizeof(float): %d\n",sizeof(float)); printf("sizeof(double): %d\n",sizeof(double)); printf("sizeof(char): %d\n",sizeof(char)); printf("sizeof(167): %d\n",sizeof(167)); printf("sizeof(3.1415926): %d\n",sizeof(3.1415926)); printf("sizeof('$') :%d\n",sizeof('$')); return 0; } compiling command used: gcc myweek06.C

Comment: @user292489: change the filename. the capitalized "C" from "myweek06.C" to "myweek06.c". And then compile with "gcc myweek06.c"

Comment: i really apprtiate you all, it works when i try to compile using g++, instead of using gcc myweek06.c, but am still not quite sure why it did not compile it using gcc.

Comment: @user292489: that is because gcc accepts the extension ".C" only for c++. To compile c you have to use ".c"

Comment: well, never knew that would make a difference, that worked perfetclly,
another Q: how can we identify the implicit and explicit cast for the following expression in c;
int a = 2, b = 3;
float f = 2.5;
double d = -1.2;
int int_result;
float real_result;

Comment: @user292489: That should be a separate StackOverflow question. :-)

Comment: well, never knew that would make a difference, that worked perfetclly, another Q: how can we identify the implicit and explicit cast for the following expression in c; 1) int a = 2, b = 3;(2) float f = 2.5; (3) double d = -1.2; (4) int int_result; (5) float real_result;

Comment: @user292489:  That should be a different question.  In fact, there's one like it, and it suffers from the problem that there is no such thing as an implicit cast.  A cast is, by definition, explicit.

Comment: @paxdiablo 
Hi paxdiablo!your answer is right but I think there should be %ul instead of %d because the sizeof() function returns number of bytes require to store certain datatype and size in memory is unsigned so use of proper format specifier is good. Even %d is also ok.

Comment: @Param, it *should* be %zu as I note in the code comment but this is a C99 feature from memory and not available in all compilers that I'm forced to cater for. If you have a look in my comment to David Thornley's answer, not even %ul is *fully* safe since it's possible for a size_t to have more bits than an unsigned long.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(int) = %ul\n", (unsigned long) sizeof(int));
}
```

with a lot of similar lines will do.  Save, compile, and run.

One common mistake is `printf("sizeof(int) = %d", sizeof(int));`, but this is a mismatch.  The result of `sizeof()` is `size_t`, which is an unsigned integral type that's big enough to hold any possible object size.  The `%d` specifier asks for an `int`, which is a signed integral type that's convenient for calculation.  It's not all that rare for `size_t` to be bigger than `int`, and then you're passing arguments of a size that the function doesn't expect, and that can be bad.

Comment: Actually, @David, I don't think that will cut it either. The standard states "The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t should not have an integer conversion rank greater than that of signed long int *unless the implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary*." (my italics) - that means the size_t is allowed to be greater than an unsigned long in a conforming implementation. The %zu format pattern is the only *guaranteed* way to ensure there won't be problems.

Comment: @paxdiablo:  You're correct in the general case.  I was oversimplifying because it actually didn't matter in the OP's case, and I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a console application, you could use writeline that takes a string and displays it:

```
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(int));
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(int));
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(float));
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(double));
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(char));
Console.WriteLine(sizeof (167));
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(3.1415926));
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(‘$’));
```

Comment: I'm not sure that sizeof(167) will even compile, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Slaks - Yeah there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Only with `unsafe`.  Also, it only operates on types, not values.

Comment: well, i gues it seems confusing because i did mention, it is meant to ask for the number of bytes for each value in unix system.

Comment: Also, you mean `ToString`.  Finally, you don't need `\n` or `ToString`.

Comment: here is the program that i tried to compile:
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    printf("sizeof(int): %d\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(float): %d\n",sizeof(float));
    printf("sizeof(double): %d\n",sizeof(double));
    printf("sizeof(char): %d\n",sizeof(char));
    printf("sizeof(167): %d\n",sizeof(167));
    printf("sizeof(3.1415926): %d\n",sizeof(3.1415926));
    printf("sizeof('$') :%d\n",sizeof('$'));
        return 0;
    }
compiling command used:
gcc myweek06.C

Comment: Isn't this C#, not C? (Ah, I see, the tag's been changed.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not working on C from last three years. But following is the answer of your question.
You can print size of different data types as follows:

printf("Size of integer: %ul",sizeof(int));

printf("Size of float: %ul",sizeof(float));

printf("Size of double: %ul",sizeof(double));

printf("Size of char: %ul",sizeof(char));

printf("Size of 167: %ul",sizeof (167));

printf("Size of 3.1415926: %ul",sizeof(3.1415926));

printf("Size of integer: %ul",sizeof(‘$’));

Just paste above printf lines in your program. You will get the size of the datatypes.

Here  sizeof() is a function which returns the total memory required to store that datatype or literal.