# C++ - How to use bitfields

Tags: c++, bit-fields

So I recently came across something like this

```
unsigned char ch : 7;
```

inside a `struct`. I read about it a little. Apparently these are called bit fields. They are used to set the width of data that a `char` can receive.
But how do we use these things. For example, I know that we can set variable `ch` to be a byte

```
unsigned char ch = 0x61;
cout << ch << endl;
```

This will output

```
a
```

However, what do we do with the bitfields?

```
unsigned char ch : 7;
ch = 0x61;                //This doesn't work for some reason

unsigned char ch : 7;
unsigned char ch = 0x61;  //Neither does this.
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Bitfields only work inside of `class`, `struct`, and `union` types.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Comment: I see. But how can they be used from withing a struct. what can they do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bitfields can only be used inside structured data types, i.e. `struct`, `class`, and `union` types. The purpose is to allow you to pack multiple members inside a single byte, without having to write lots of explicit shifts and masks. For instance, you can write:

```
struct halfbyte_t {
    unsigned int half1: 4;
    unsigned int half2: 4;
} halfbyte;
```

This declares a variable named `halfbyte` that contains two 4-bit members, which will be packed into a single 8-bit byte, rather than having to use 2 bytes if you just declared them `unsigned char`.

You access them just like any other structure member:

```
halfbyte.half1 = 3;
cout << halfbyte.half3;
```

1-bit fields are especially useful if you have lots of boolean flags in a structure, since you don't have to have a separate byte for each flag.

```
struct flag_t {
    unsigned int flag1: 1;
    unsigned int flag2: 1;
    unsigned int flag3: 1;
    unsigned int flag4: 1;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks. that was a good explanation. I have a follow-up question though. When you said that the two halfbytes could be packed into an 8-bit character, How exactly would I do that?

Comment: @Q_A The most portable and semantically correct would be with arithmetic, e.g. `(half1 << 4) | half2` or the other way around. You could hack it with unions or reinterpret casts, but the results won't always be consistent. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376426/order-of-fields-when-using-a-bit-field-in-c. The main usage is for saving space in memory constrained environments. If you find you often need to combine their values then you might reconsider using bit fields; really they're for things that are semantically separate.

Comment: @Q_A You don't do it, it's done automatically by the compiler. That's the whole point.

Comment: The layout of bit-fields is non-portable, so they are of limited use if you are trying to write portable code

Comment: @M.M that's a sweeping statement and more FUD sans an explanation of "*limited*": code can portably use them for the functionality described in this answer, they're just not portable usable in raw binary I/O - but the same can be said of e.g. `int` due to endianness and the variety of encodings (sign magnitude, 2s complement...).

Comment: Do people use bit fields of size 1 for individual flags? That is, instead of defining, say, 16 const unsigned ints and performing the typical bit manipulation and testing algebra, I define a struct with 16 bit fields and use them like normal members, essentially? (I think I never need to test for "none set" in my use case.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Your method has the advantage that the values are portable, so it's very common when defining protocols and file data formats. The layout of bit fields is implementation-dependent, so it's only useful for data structures used internally.