# Separating bits in a bitfield

Tags: c, bit-fields

Lets say I have a bitfield structure:

```
typedef struct{
   unsigned int a:2;
   unsigned int b:4;
   unsigned int c:4;
}bf1
```

And lets say I have set the bits like this:

```
bf1.a=2;
bf1.b=9;
bf1.c=8;
```

Now, I want to separate the bitfield into two parts of 5 and 5.
If the bits currently look like this `1000100110`
I want to separate it into `10001 -> 17` and `00110 -> 6`.

Comment: C does not provide means to manipulate bit-fields like this, merging and separating them. Write code to put the bits together in an `unsigned int` and then to take them apart into the fields you want.

Comment: See: [Order of fields when using a bit field in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19376426/589924)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up the compiler to decide the order of the fields in a bit-field.

> The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.

So what you are trying to achieve is not possible using bit fields unless you target a specific compiler and platform. (You would use a union of bit fields if the order was predictable.)

You will therefore need to perform the bit manipulations manually.

```c
unsigned bf =
     ( 8 << 8 )
   | ( 9 << 4 )
   | ( 2 << 0 );

unsigned x = ( bf >> 5 ) & 0x1F;  // `& MASK` not needed for most significant field.
unsigned y = ( bf >> 0 ) & 0x1F;
```

or

```c
unsigned bf = 0;

bf = ( bf & ~0x3C0 ) | ( 8 << 8 );
bf = ( bf & ~0x03C ) | ( 9 << 4 );
bf = ( bf & ~0x003 ) | ( 2 << 0 );

unsigned x = ( bf >> 5 ) & 0x1F;  // `& MASK` not needed for most significant field.
unsigned y = ( bf >> 0 ) & 0x1F;
```

The second version works even if the field isn't previously zero.

Of course, this code can be cleaned up using defines and functions. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19376742/589924) to an earlier question for an example.

Comment: ABI usally defines bitfiled order