# C struct interpretation works incorrectly with bitfields

Tags: c, linux, memory, struct, bit-fields

I need to identically interpret first 2 bits of first byte in memory (which came from the wire) with different C structs (network header descriptors). This is the minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct some {
        uint8_t reserved : 6;
        uint8_t flags : 2;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct some2 {
        uint16_t b : 12; 
        uint16_t reserved : 2;
        uint16_t flags : 2;
} __attribute__((packed));

int main(void)
{
        char *ptr = malloc(8);
        ptr[0] = 0xC0;
        ptr[1] = 0x00;

        struct some *hdr = (struct some *)ptr;
        printf("%zu %u\n", sizeof(struct some), hdr->flags);

        struct some2 *hdr2 = (struct some2 *)ptr;
        printf("%zu %u\n", sizeof(struct some2), hdr2->flags);

        return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
1 3
2 0
```

**What is the reason of interpreting flags in the second struct as 0? Is there any error in `struct some2` definition?**

[Order of fields when using a bit field in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376426/order-of-fields-when-using-a-bit-field-in-c) postulates

> C standard allows compiler to put bit-fields in any order. There is no
> reliable and portable way to determine the order.

But there is no putting through the bit-field mechanism from compiler code, this is just a byte from network, which I'm interpreting through the bit-field mechanism..

**UPD**

As Eric mentioned the one solution is to re-define struct such a way:

```
struct some2 {
        uint8_t b1 : 4;
        uint8_t reserved : 2;
        uint8_t flags : 2;
        uint8_t b2; 
} __attribute__((packed));
```

But it I need to access the full `b` number of 12 bits, it will cause some ugly concatenation of 4-bit and 8-bit parts..

Comment: Probably something to do with endiannesss, but since you can't assume the order of bitfields your approach is non-portable even if you figure this out.  Why not just use bit masking to figure out the flags in a reliable way?

Comment: @StephenNewell I don't need portable code, anyway this code is platform-related. Bitfield-endianess #ifdefs are omitted from this example. Bit masking is the way, of course, but I need to interpret several subsequent bytes, and update it before sending

Comment: Re “I need to identically interpret 2 bits of one byte in memory (which came from the wire) with different C structs (network header descriptors)”: No, you do not. You may need to interpret two bits of one byte, but you do not need to interpret it with different C structures. In fact, you do not need to use structures at all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The common approach of reading/writing with network traffic (headers) is to use packed C structs with bitfields if needed (Linux kernel, DPDK and so on). This approach it not one and only of course

Comment: @budoattack: Regardless of what the common approach is, you do not have a **need** to interpret one byte with two structure types. Framing the problem correctly is important for determining a solution. Your need is to interpret bits. As my answer shows, it is impossible, given your compiler’s currently bit-field layout method (might be alterable with switches) to define a structure with a two-bit field mapped to bits 6-7 of the first byte and another field mapped to other bits in the first two bytes. Adapt your solution to the actual requirements, not what other people commonly do.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, I totally agree that solution depends on actual requirements. Usually, first of all, you focus on some best practices though.. Updated question with your idea

Comment: Re "*It will cause some ugly concatenation*", Fix the byte order using `ntohs`. Added to my answer.

Comment: "Hey doc, it hurts when I do this."  "Then don't do this!"

Answer (score 1):

On an little-endian machine with an 8-bit `char`, the `uint16_t` with the byte pattern `C0 00` will be 0x00C0, not 0xC000 as you seem to expect.

If, on this machine, the fields are ordered such that the first field is uses the least significant bits, the next field uses the next least significant bits, etc, then your code is equivalent to

```c
uint8_t *hdr1 = (uint8_t *)ptr;     // *hdr1 == 0xC0
printf( "%zu %u\n", sizeof( *hdr1 ), ( *hdr1 >> ( 6      ) ) & 0x3 );  // 1 3

uint16_t *hdr2 = (uint16_t *)ptr;   // *hdr2 == 0x00C0
printf( "%zu %u\n", sizeof( *hdr2 ), ( *hdr2 >> ( 12 + 2 ) ) & 0x3 );  // 2 0
```

If the value of the field is supposed to be 0xC000—i.e. it's in "network" (big-endian) byte order—then you can fix it using `ntohs`.

Answer (score 0):

In `struct some`, you have told the compiler to lay out a six-bit field and a two-bit field. In `struct some2`, you have told the compiler to lay out a 12-bit field, a two-bit field, and another two-bit field.

The compiler did so. For the first structure, it laid out the six-bit `reserved` field as bits 0-5 of the first (and only) byte, and it laid out the two-bit `flags` field as bits 6-7 of the byte. (Here, bits are numbered with 0 as the position with the least significant value when interpreted as a binary numeral and 7 as the most.)

For the second structure, it laid out the 12-bit `b` field as bits 0-7 of the first byte and bits 0-3 of the second byte (equivalently, bits 0-11 of the `uint16_t` formed from the two bytes in little-endian order), the two-bit `reserved` field as bits 4-5 of the second byte, and the two-bit `flags` field as bits 6-7 of the second byte.

In `hdr->flags`, you accessed one byte, which had been set to C0<sub>16</sub>, using a `struct some` type. This interpreted bits 6-7 of the byte as two-bit `flags` field, yielding 3.

In `hdr2->flags`, you accessed two bytes, the second of which had not been set to any value, using a `struct some2` type. This interpreted bits 6-7 of the second byte as the two-bit `flags` field. The byte apparently contained zeros in these bits, at least in effect, yielding 0.

If you want to rely on your compiler’s layout of bit-fields then you need to define the structures differently, so that the `flags` field of `struct some2` corresponds to bits 6-7 of the first byte. Given your compiler’s apparent behavior, you need to define a six-bit field (or fields totaling six bits) prior to `uint8_t flags : 2`. That compels those six bits before `flags` to be separate from a bit-field following `flags`, so there is no way to define a single 12-bit `b` field that includes both bits 0-5 from the first byte and additional bits from the second byte.

Alternatively, you can access the byte using a character type and use the shift operator to extract bits 6-7.

Answer (score 0):

As you point out yourself:

> C standard allows compiler to put bit-fields in any order. There is no reliable and portable way to determine the order.

So, there's no compatible way to make two structures with different lists of bitfields to be collocated in memory int the same place, and order, in a portable way.  Only if you declare **the same bitfields** and **in the same order**, with no other bitfields apart of the ones you have includes, and **compile them with the same compiler** will those structures be compatible.

But beware, that even in that case it is not warranted that the two 1 bits you put in the data initializer (as you do in your code) will match the positions of the bitfield you desire.  **Once you decide to use bit fields, you are tied to a single compiler.**  Don't search the standard, nor try to be portable, if you use bitfields.

The alternative is to start by using a nework format (like e.g. `char [1500]`, and extract from the appropiate byte the bits you are trying to use, and put them ---with a normal assignment--- into the bitfields of the now host format structure)  That code will be portable and will not even require the non portable use of the `__attribute__((packed))` compiler directive.  Something like:

```
struct some var = {0};
var.flags = (packet[0] & FLAGS_MASK) >> FLAGS_SHIFT;
/* now you have the flags in host format */
```

(Beware that some protocols transmit the bits MSB first and others in LSB first. Probably you'll have to change the order of bits or define your flags appropiately.)

Indeed, for the first structure you have three fields of 6 and 2 bits, while in the second you have three fields of 12, 2 and 2.  It's very umprobable that the flag field goes in the same place in both structures.  You were lucky of finding the two 11 bits in the first case, but most probably the 12 bitplaces first field has moved the `flags` field to the second byte.