# Convert struct to char array in C

Tags: c, pointers, networking

I have below structure which I need to send across a network.

```
typedef struct {
    u_int16_t dataSize;
    u_int16_t *positions;
    char *dataLoad;
} TransferData
```

positions and dataLoad variables can contain any number of ints and characters.

I have tried this using,

```
TransferData m;

//adding data to the structure
size_t len = snprintf(NULL, len, "%p, %d, %s", m.positions, m.dataSize, m.dataLoad);
char *apstr = calloc(1, sizeof *apstr * len + 1);
if (!apstr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory allocation failed.\n", __func__);
}

if (snprintf(apstr, len + 1, "%p,%d,%s",m.positions,m.dataSize,m.dataLoad) > len + 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s() error: snprintf returned truncated result.\n", __func__);

}
```

The code works for char* and u_int16_t but not for u_int16_t *.Is there any way that I can convert this struct to a char array??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing a struct over TCP (SOCK\_STREAM) socket in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000851/passing-a-struct-over-tcp-sock-stream-socket-in-c)

Comment: Please define "does not work".

Comment: Depending on what `m->positions` ought to contain you have to marshall the corresponding entries by dereferencing the pointer. Just obtaining the pointer value is useless on the other end of the network.

Comment: %s is much different than %p. `positions` and `dataLoad` will be treated differently by the format specifiers. %s will dereference the pointer and print the contents as ASCII characters. %p will simply print the address contained in the pointer. You will need to do something different to get the contents of `positions`.

Comment: Adding to the comment by Ctx, what do you want to do with a character representation of a pointer/address, once it traveled via network to a different computer? Chances that it makes sense in whatever address space is active there seem close to zero.