# Sending a structure through a socket in c

Tags: c, sockets, data-structures, tcp, structure

I want to send a data structure through a socket in a tcp server/client program written in C. However when i try to print the sent data it doesn't print anything. I've realized by now that sending structures this way is a bad idea, the posts i've seen aren't being very helpful in finding a way to actually make this work. Here's the data structure in question:

```
#define BUFFSIZE 1024
#define USERLEN 32
#define OPTLEN 16

struct  message{
  char option[OPTLEN];
  char user[USERLEN];
  char buff[BUFFSIZE]; 
  char target[USERLEN];
  int sockid;
};
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read through this previous answer to a very similar question. At what point does that not work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000851/passing-a-struct-over-tcp-sock-stream-socket-in-c

Comment: just cast it to a char array to serialize it and if you need to restrict it to actual charrs then just base64 encode it

Comment: The only part that might cause problems is the `sockid`.  There's a question of how often your `buff` will actually contain 1000+ characters vs just a few; it might be better to send only the active characters for such a long field, but the others could probably be sent entire.  Look up "serialization" -- that's the process you need to send the data, and "deserialization" to receive it.

Comment: If you want to use binary protocol I suggest protobuf from Google :)

Answer (score 3):

For the same machines and compilers you can do as follows:

```
// define your structure:
#define BUFFSIZE 1024
#define USERLEN 32
#define OPTLEN 16

typedef struct message{
  char option[OPTLEN];
  char user[USERLEN];
  char buff[BUFFSIZE]; 
  char target[USERLEN];
  int sockid;
}my_message;


// now you can use it in your program

my_message m;

// initialize m
...
strcpy(m.user,"1234");
...
m.sockid = sockfd;

// send it over 

if ((nbytes = write(sockfd, &m, sizeof(my_message)) != sizeof(my_message))
{
  printf("error writing my message");
}



// read the message on the other side:
...
my_message received_message;
int size;

if( (size = recv ( sockfd, (void*)&received_message, sizeof(my_message), 0)) >= 0)
{
     // check the size
}

// It would work for same machines 32/64 bits and same compilers.
```

If you need better portability try [protobuf-c](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c) , [nanopb](http://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/), binary serialization [binn](https://github.com/liteserver/binn) or [tpl](http://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/).

Comment: will the send() return after its recv() on other end? Im asking because, if we use a malloc'ed object of struct, when can we free the object?

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the message out on the socket:

```
struct message mymess;
...
write(socketfd, &mymess, sizeof(struct message));
```

and then read it back in on the client side. That works if it's always the same hardware / compiler, since the struct will be compiled the same way. If you haven't memset() the whole of mymess, then you are likely to have uninitialized stuff in the write(). It should be safe, but can set off sanity checks.

For more reliable messaging you need to design or adopt a serialization protocol. JSON is an extremely popular one (albeit perhaps not among C programmers), but there are many others.

Answer (score 1):

Before, writing a structure, you need to be aware of padding issues. It seems that your structure is well aligned. However, the receiver needs to be on similar architecture and similar compiler structure packaging settings to consume the structure in the same exact way. Alternatively, you can define a message protocol that explicitly packs this data and writes as a byte stream.

That said, a structure could still be written simply by doing
write(sock, &myMessage, sizeof (message)). It will write out all the bytes of the sizeof(message).