# How does the compiler handle the misalignment?

Tags: c, gcc, padding, compiler-optimization

The SO question [Does GCC's `__attribute__((__packed__))`…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756811/does-gccs-attribute-packed/7956942#7956942) mentions that `__attribute__((__packed__))` does "packing which introduces alignment issues when accessing the fields of a packed structure. The compiler will account for that when the the fields are accessed directly, but not when they are accessed via pointers".

How does the compiler makes sure that the fields are accessed directly? I suppose it internally add some padding or does some pointer magic. In the case below, how does the compiler makes sure that the `y` is accessed correctly compared to the pointer?

```
struct packet {
    uint8_t x;
    uint32_t y;
} __attribute__((packed));

int main ()
{
    uint8_t bytes[5] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 2};
    struct packet *p = (struct packet *)bytes;

    // compiler handles misalignment because it knows that
    // "struct packet" is packed
    printf("y=%"PRIX32", ", ntohl(p->y));

    // compiler does not handle misalignment - py does not inherit
    // the packed attribute
    uint32_t *py = &p->y;
    printf("*py=%"PRIX32"\n", ntohl(*py));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can summon someone to your question by mentioning their name in the `@` notation; they have to have made a comment already (to this question) and your comment is then a reply to theirs.  So you should not be surprised if Ambroz does not notice this question because of your comment.

Comment: You cannot use the at sign syntax to ping someone unless they've already participated in the thread in which you're posting. Addressing a question to a specific user is also inappropriate here. This isn't a chat room or "be my personal consultant or teacher" site.

Comment: This is one of those for which the target is of extreme importance. For example alignment isn't even really a thing on z80, mostly optional on x86, but critical on some RISC architecture. So, for what target do you want to consider this question?

Comment: @harold: basically i work on embedded environment which uses arm.Anyway this question is answered by Barmer excellent reply.

Comment: For ARM it depends on the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the compiler sees the notation `p->y`, it knows you're accessing a structure member, and that the structure is packed, because of the declaration of `p`. It translates this into code that reads byte by byte, and performs the necessary bit shifting to combine them into a `uint32_t` variable. Essentially, it treats the expression `p->y` as if it were something like:

```
*((char*)p+3) << 24 + *((char*)p+2) << 16 + *((char*p)+1) << 8 + *(char*)p
```

But when you indirect through `*py`, the compiler doesn't know where the value of that variable came from. It doesn't know that it points into a packed structure, so that it would need to perform this shifting. `py` is declared to point to `uint32_t`, which can normally be accessed using an instruction that reads an entire 32-bit word at once. But this instruction expects the pointer to be aligned to a 4-byte boundary, so when you try to do this you'll get a bus error due to the misalignment.

Comment: @Barmer: oh that is why i remember sometime back somewhere that the misaligned memory access causing more reads than aligned memory access as compiler issues more instructions for reading the memory compare to aligned access. So in the case of misaligned integer access  the compiler issues 4 instructions to get integer memory compare to only one access in the case of aligned memory right?

Comment: Is it though? An unaligned read like that is just one instruction on x86, unless the compiler is being silly.

Comment: It depends on the specific hardware architecture.