# Why redudant attribute DW_AT_endianity with TAG_variable and TAG_base_type?

Tags: dwarf

I was reading DWARFv4 spec and came across attribute DW_AT_endianity.

Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

As per spec, Two of the tag values TAG_variable and TAG_base_type both can have that attribute.

But as far as, i understand when you create a TAG_variable you have to pass the "Type", which can be of TAG_base_type(others are also possible).
So my question is if we are setting DW_AT_endianity on TAG_variable, why TAG_base_type also supports that attribute.

In other words every variable is of some type and can have that attribute, so why need attribute support for both type and variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DW_AT_endianity` attribute was the [response to a proposed C compiler extension allowing the "creation of data in both big and little endian formats".](http://dwarfstd.org/ShowIssue.php?issue=031002.2)  It appears that the attribute was intended for base types (like [this example](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/628951)) or structs/unions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40974179/1579636)).  Using the same attribute for both a simple variable and its underlying base type would, as you say, be redundant — note that the attribute is optional (see DWARF 4, sections 4.1.12 and 5.1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the links are very much helpful. can you direct me to an example of where the DW_AT_endianity is used in TAG_variable, instead of pointing to TAG_type with that attribute? (apologies in advance about it, i tried but not able to find it using google.)

Comment: Just read your old answer(posted before editing), which cleared my confusion, thanks.

Comment: @Chirag Patel: please disregard the first version of my answer as the example I gave is misleading -- the DWARF Issue I cited states explicitly that the intention is to mark types **or** objects.  I'm not aware of any examples of `DW_AT_endianity` being used for a variable rather than its type but I don't think this has any significance.  Permitting the attribute in data objects as well as types may simply reflect an expansion of the goal in order to create a flexible and future-proof interface.  Whether or not a language or compiler actually uses a feature, however, is up to its author.