# Endianness for length shorter than word but more than a byte

Tags: arrays, endianness, bit

There are 3 fields in a 4bytes of a packet of length 8, 12 and 12 bits. Each field should be encoded in little endian format. How do I reliably encode fields which are shorter than a word? Is reversing the bit the only option?

--
Thanks.

Comment: maybe useful? [How Endianness Effects Bitfield Packing](http://mjfrazer.org/mjfrazer/bitfields/) Also, [C/C++: Force Bit Field Order and Alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490092/c-c-force-bit-field-order-and-alignment)

Comment: Thanks. First link is promising.