# Packing bits and reading them - C

Tags: c, bit-shift

Here are declarations of what I am sending to my server:

```
typedef enum 
{
    GET = 0,
    SET = 1,
    UNDEF = 2,

} cmd_t;

struct  args 
{ 
    cmd_t cmd; 
    uint8_t value; 
    uint8_t id;
};
```

`value` is of type `uint8_t` and has for example value `42` and `id` is also `uint8_t` and has value `30`. `cmd` is my `typedef` and is for example `GET` also `0`.

I send this info to server packed like this:

```
char buff[2];
buff[0] = arguments.cmd;
buff[0] += arguments.id << 2;

buff[1] = arguments.value;
send(sfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
```

I pack in the first byte on the first 2 bits my `cmd`, then shift it 2 bits and pack the `id`. Then on the second byte I pack `value`. I know that value can't be bigger than `127` so I can leave it on the first 7 bits of my byte. I also know that id can't be greather that `63`.

[image: Here is what I mean:]

Then I receive that on my server. When I read second byte of my response also `req[1]` I get value `42`, but when I read my first byte also `req[0]` however I shift it I can't get `0` or `30`. req is delared as `req[2]`. Here is what I tried:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
       int idCMD = (uint8_t) (req[0]>>i);
       printf("idCMD -> %d\n", idCMD);
    }
    printf("\n");
     for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
       int idCMD = (uint8_t) (req[0]<<i);
       printf("idCMD -> %d\n", idCMD);
    }
```

How do I read my cmd and id?

output:

```
    idCMD -> 121
    idCMD -> 60
    idCMD -> 30
    idCMD -> 15
    idCMD -> 7
    idCMD -> 3
    idCMD -> 1
    idCMD -> 0

    idCMD -> 121
    idCMD -> 242
    idCMD -> 228
    idCMD -> 200
    idCMD -> 144
    idCMD -> 32
    idCMD -> 64
    idCMD -> 128
```

What I got out of this is that:

```
    printf("value -> %d\n", req[1]);
    printf("id -> %d\n", req[0] >> 2);
    printf("cmd-> %d\n", req[0] >> 6);

    value -> 42
    id -> 30
    cmd-> 1
```

I get that cmd is 1 also. How do I make sure that I read 0 and not 1?

but it seems that I am not reading my `cmd` right. The output above is when the `cmd` is 1. Here is when the `cmd` is 0 and value 0:

```
idCMD -> 120
idCMD -> 60
idCMD -> 30
idCMD -> 15
idCMD -> 7
idCMD -> 3
idCMD -> 1
idCMD -> 0

idCMD -> 120
idCMD -> 240
idCMD -> 224
idCMD -> 192
idCMD -> 128
idCMD -> 0
idCMD -> 0
idCMD -> 0
value -> 0
id -> 30
cmd-> 1
```

How do I read cmd correctly and is this correct interpretation?

Comment: What value **do** you get in `req[0]`?  And where is your code for receiving the data?

Comment: Also, how is `req` declared?  If it's a signed type, shifting may not work the way you expect.  Likewise, you probably want to declare `buff` as `unsigned char buff[2]` or `uint8_t buff[2]`.

Comment: You need to also mask the bits with `&`. `buff[0]` should be formed with `|=`.

Comment: Use bit fields - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny: I disagree as to bitfields, especially if you need to have a well-defined protocol over the wire.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us the actual output.

Comment: pack: byte[0] = (id<<2 ) | (0x3 & cmd); then unpack: id=byte[0]>>2; cmd = byte[0]&0x3

Comment: `req[0] >> 6`. Where does the `6` come from? And why shift? Your diagram clearly shows `cmd` is already in the bottom 2 bits and does not require any shifting. Should be `req[0] &0x3`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef enum 
{
    GET = 0,
    SET = 1,
    UNDEF = 2,

} cmd_t;

struct  args 
{ 
    cmd_t cmd; 
    uint8_t value; 
    uint8_t id;
};

int main(){
    char buff[2];
    struct  args arguments;
    arguments.cmd=UNDEF;
    arguments.id=23;//256/4=64 range 0~63



    buff[0] = arguments.cmd;
    buff[0] += arguments.id << 2;
    buff[1] = arguments.value;



    printf("%d\n",buff[0]&0b11);
    printf("%d",(buff[0]&0b11111100)>>2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why to apply mask before shifting right? You will lose those bits anyway. And why to use arithmetic operations when you combine 2 values into single byte when you have bit OR operation?

Comment: becase in this case wont cause any problem.

Comment: OP need a quick answer to know than a good answer,otherwise wont ask such easy question,i don't want make him confuse

Comment: If he need strict ,will see other respond together

Answer (score -1):

If you just want easy way,this is another choose union+struct

you can define how many bits per member in struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef enum 
{
    GET = 0,
    SET = 1,
    UNDEF = 2,

} cmd_t;


union args_v2{
    uint8_t raw[2];

    struct {
        uint8_t cmd: 2;//2bits
        uint8_t id: 6;//6bits
        uint8_t value:  8;//8bits
    };
};
int main(){


    union args_v2 arguments_2;
    arguments_2.id=32;
    arguments_2.cmd=UNDEF;
    arguments_2.value=77;
    printf("\nPack Size%d\n",sizeof(arguments_2));
    printf("\nRaw %d %d\n",arguments_2.raw[0],arguments_2.raw[1]);//130=32*4+2
    //
    printf("\nid:%d cmd:%d value:%d\n",arguments_2.id,arguments_2.cmd,arguments_2.value);





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think using structs/unions/bitfields is a good idea for a network protocol, since if the client and server are running on different systems (or were built with different compilers), they may not be using the same layout, and then everything breaks.

Comment: you think little endian problem , so i declare using uint8_t array not uint16_t,so never cause your problem – Nate Eldredge

Comment: I have experience about this

Comment: I don't think that helps.  ["The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490092/c-c-force-bit-field-order-and-alignment).  You simply can't guarantee that any two compilers will lay out your struct in the same way.  Maybe most common compilers will do so, in this case, but I still don't think it's a good practice in general.

Comment: thats why i use uint_8 not uint_16

Comment: i dont what argue any more about this