# Using bit fields within a single byte

Tags: c, bit-fields

I'm familiar with the problems of using bit fields when communicating between processors -- see [C/C++: Force Bit Field Order and Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490092/c-c-force-bit-field-order-and-alignment) and why endian-ness figures into the issue.

But my question is about using bit fields to specify the layout of bits within a one-byte register: Is it safe?

As a concrete example, I'm working with a device with a byte-wide control register documented as follows:

| D7 (msb) | D6 | D5 | D4 | D3:D2 | D1 | D0 (lsb) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vbias | Mode | Trigger | 3-wire | Fault Code | Fault | 50 Hz |

It would seem natural to define the following `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int vbias : 1;
  unsigned int mode : 1;
  unsigned int trigger : 1;
  unsigned int wire_3 : 1;
  unsigned int fault_code : 2;
  unsigned int fault : 1;
  unsigned int hz_50 : 1
} control_reg_t;
```

So the question: As I'm only using this `struct` within a given processor -- it will not be transmitted over the wire, etc -- is there any reason NOT to use this approach?

## update

This is not a good approach for defining bits within a register, even if the struct stays local to one machine.  As has been pointed out below, the ordering of the bits is compiler dependent, so `vbias` may end up as the most significant bit or the least significant bit.

Moral: unless you can guarantee which compiler is used to compile your code, don't use structs and bit fields to define the layout of registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C Standard states that:

> The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to
> low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.

This means that whether `vbias` inhabits the most significant bit or least significant bit of the unit (`int`) is implementation-defined. So unless you are sure you already know the behavior on your system and that you will only use your code on that particular system, bit-fields will not make the cut.

As far as I can tell, that is not actually contingent on the byte-order of your system.

Given that your control register specifies which items belong in which bits of significance but C bit-fields do not, I would suggest storing your flags as a `uint8_t` if available or otherwise a `unsigned char`, and [access them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/16217248) as follows:

```
#define get_vbias(x) (((x) >> 7) & 1)
#define get_mode(x) (((x) >> 6) & 1)
#define get_trigger(x) (((x) >> 5) & 1)
#define get_wire_3(x) (((x) >> 4) & 1)
#define get_fault_code(x) (((x) >> 2) & 3)
#define get_fault(x) (((x) >> 1) & 1)
#define get_hz_50(x) ((x) & 1)
```

And in case setting them the same way you would set the bit-field of a `struct` is [appropriate for your use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78212571/using-bit-fields-within-a-single-byte/78212662?noredirect=1#comment137886474_78212662):

```
#define set(x, n, b) (((x) & ~(1 << (n))) | (!!(b) << (n)))
#define set_vbias(x, b) set((x), 7, (b))
#define set_mode(x, b) set((x), 6, (b))
#define set_trigger(x, b) set((x), 5, (b))
#define set_wire_3(x) set((x), 4, (b))
#define set_fault(x) set((x), 1, (b))
#define set_hz_50(x) set((x), 0, (b))
// Handle this one separately because the rest are just one bit
#define set_fault_code(x, n) (((x) & ~(3 << 2)) | (((n) & 3) << 2))
```

Extracting them manually using bitwise operators will guarantee which item inhabits the LSB, MSB, and each bit in between.

Comment: This shows how to read the fields, but OP likely needs to set them too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Setting control registers using bitfields is a bad pattern, since hardware registers often don't behave like RAM.  Often times, control registers will need to have specific bits written to trigger actions while irrelevant bits are written as zero.  Performing a read-modify-write sequence may cause actions to get erroneously retriggered.

Comment: @supercat: This answer is not about writing control registers using bit-fields, and I did not say anything about whether or not a read-modify-write sequence should be used. The fact is a control register needs to be written, as that is the nature of a control register, and therefore there needs to be some way to put values in desired bits in it, which is what I suggested this author provide.

Answer (score 2):

> As I'm only using this `struct` within a given processor -- it will not be transmitted over the wire, etc -- is there any reason NOT to use this approach?

Because the total number of bits is not greater than 8, you can rely on all of them being packed into the same addressable storage unit, but you cannot rely on

- that unit being only 8-bits wide
- which end of the ASU contains the bitfields
- the order of the bits within the part of the ASU they occupy.
- the size of the structure being the same as the size of the ASU

It is *possible* that your approach would work as you want with particular C implementations.  If you find an implementation where it does, then you should be able to rely on it doing so consistently *with that implementation*.  But it is not safe to assume that it will work with any particular implementation, and of course, that means it's not portable.

Bitfields almost never should be used.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you stick to a single hardware implementation *and* use the same compiler and same set of compiler flags, you *should* get consistent behavior.

That being said, the layout of the fields will depend on the endianness of the machine in question.  If you're working with big endian, the order is fine.  If you're working with little endian, you'll need to reverse the fields.  Also, you'll need to change the base type to `unsigned char` so that the struct is 1 byte wide instead of 4.

For example, if you're using gcc, you can use the following:

```
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__

typedef struct {
  unsigned char hz_50 : 1
  unsigned char fault : 1;
  unsigned char fault_code : 2;
  unsigned char wire_3 : 1;
  unsigned char trigger : 1;
  unsigned char mode : 1;
  unsigned char vbias : 1;
} control_reg_t;

#elseif __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__

typedef struct {
  unsigned char vbias : 1;
  unsigned char mode : 1;
  unsigned char trigger : 1;
  unsigned char wire_3 : 1;
  unsigned char fault_code : 2;
  unsigned char fault : 1;
  unsigned char hz_50 : 1
} control_reg_t;

#else

#error "unknown endianness"

#endif
```

Comment: I didn't know about compiler defs of a byte's bit order. But what does it have to do with a machine's (byte order) endianness?

Comment: @WeatherVane The ordering of bits in a bitfield is implementation defined, and typically go along with the machine endianness, so it controls endianness at both the byte and the bit level.  This is more apparent if you push such a struct directly over the network.  Also, if you look at the definition of `struct iphdr` in /usr/include/netinet/ip.h, you'll see that it uses this same construct to control the ordering of the version and header length fields.

Comment: As far as I am aware, either bit order can be used, regardless of endianness.  Also, the ASU containing the bitfields can be larger than 8 bits, so the spec does not guarantee even that the bitfields appear in the first byte of the structure -- which for its part can be larger than the ASU, possibly causing other problems.

Comment: So bit order is a feature of the compiler, while byte order is a property of the machine? Which machines have reverse bit-order?